# Make a circle inside a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to make a circle inside a matrix. For example; Make a matrix of some dimension, let's say `ones(200,200)` and then select its circle's `x` and `y` co-ordinates and change the color of these selected pixels and then show the image using `imshow(img)`. As showing in the picture. Is it possible?

[image]

**OR**

Can I change this ploting code to picture for using the circle functionality?

```
radius = 5; 
centerX = 20;
centerY = 30;
viscircles([centerX, centerY], radius);
axis square;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `meshgrid` to create a grid of `x` and `y` coordinates and then use the equation of the circle to check whether each x/y pair is within the circle or not. This will yield a logical result which can be displayed as an image

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:200, 1:200);
isinside = (x - centerX).^2 + (y - centerY).^2 <= radius^2;

imshow(isinside);
```

If you simply want the *outline* of the circle, you can apply a convolution to the resulting binary mask to decrease it's size and then subtract out the circle to yield only the outline

```
shrunk = ~conv2(double(~isinside), ones(3), 'same');
outline = isinside - shrunk;

imshow(outline)
```

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use `bwperim` to yield the binary outline

```
outline = bwperim(isinside);
imshow(outline);
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want to change the colors shown above, you can either invert `outline` and `isinside` before displaying

```
isinside = ~isinside;
outline = ~outline;

imshow(isinside)
imshow(outline)
```

Or you can invert the colormap

```
imshow(isinside)
colormap(gca, flipud(gray))
```

[image]

Comment: It is fine but the back ground color is black. I want to change it white and the circle border color into black. Circle color can be change using `conv2(double(isinside), zeros(3), 'same');` but how to change the background color?

Comment: @Humty. Subtract the array from 1.

Comment: @Suever Thanks buddy made by day.